# Asturias Playing Open B

Tags: guitar, classical-guitar

I learning Asturias in this piece we have to play open B after every base notes.

So currently my base notes sounds fine but playing open B is seems to be quite challenging. I am alternating between `M` and `I` fingers, alternation is also works fine.

But in between playing the open B notes are seems to be missing i.e my finger just touches the string so any advice or exercise  which may help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention which hand is touching and muting the open B string. If you are right handed and it is your right hand make sure you use free strokes and not rest strokes to pluck the strings. If it is your left hand you have to focus on maintaining the curvature of your fingers so the fleshy part of the fingers near the palm don’t come too close to the fingerboard. Also it is very important you hold the instrument in the proper way, between the legs with a footstool for your left leg. Practice slowly, focusing on letting the open B string ring true. Here is a video of the piece being played that has very good camera angles. It may help you to watch and make comparisons between you and her. I hope this is helpful to you.